# How to create name servers in DirectAdmin with one IP?

Tags: linux, dns, apache-http-server, control-panel, nameserver

I have a dedicated server with DA installed, and only one IP address.

How can I define a name server to point my domain to on the server? I found [this guide](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/how-to-setup-the-dns-and-name-server-for-a-directadmin-web-server/) but it talks about two IP addresses; I don't want to take my website offline so I prefer not testing those things without being sure of what I'm doing.

I've also been told that I need to create GLUE records on my registrar - can anyone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this guide :)

You can do two things:

Host your DNS with the domain name registrar or create a prof. DNS hosting account. If you do this, you need to create A records foreach domain using the server's IP address (I recommend this one)

or you use the name servers from the your web hosting provider (if this is possible)

To host your own name server you need two IP addresses even if they point to the same machine.
This is an extra risk: If your server is down anything is done.

Comment: So I guess it's just simpler to buy another IP address right?